# DEPRECATION: Using the defaultContainer is no longer supported

Tags: ember.js

I just need to insert and remove dinamically a view into the DOM;
this is the view:

```
App.LoadingEngView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName: 'assets/loadingEng'
});
```

And this is the way i insert it:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    updateCurrentPath: function() {
        ...
        var view = App.LoadingEngView.create();
    view.appendTo('body');
        ...
    }
});
```

It works but i get the deprecation warning; how can i fix this?

Comment: Could you give more background on what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, the loading view is just a piece of html that is inserted into the DOM while the application is loading some configuration files from the server, and is removed from the DOM once finished; is just a "panel" that have high z-index and stays in foreground during loading, in the middle of the screen, with a loading bar

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `Importclimbing.LoadingEngView` be `App.LoadingEngView`?

Comment: Yes this was just a typo i made writing the question; the problem persist